# Sidebar configuration

Tags: taskbar

Used to run Unix on HP servers, many years ago, and several years ago started dabbling with Linux. I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (after several years layoff), and I'm trying to load shortcuts into the sidebar/launcher bar like wot I used to do.
Is there any help on the utility to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to add shortcut to launcher, open your dash > search for the desired software > simply drag them to launcher and  you are done.